# Why doesn't this query produce a mysql_error() result?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, try-catch

I was running some code & I wasn't getting any errors, but the row wasn't being deleted either.... so I was a bit confused. So I checked out the code & found out I had a problem with my query, but at the same time it wasn't producing a true result to my test with mysql_error().

I am using the below code..

```
        try {
            // Start transaction
            beginTransaction($this->db_connection);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
        }

        try {

            // Delete main entry
            $this->removeMainEntry($lid);

            // Delete list columns
            $this->removeListColumns($lid);

            // Commit changes to database
            commitChanges($this->db_connection);

        } catch (Exception $e) {

            try {
                // Rollback changes
                rollback($this->db_connection, $e->getMessage());
            } catch (Exception $re) {
                throw new Exception($re->getMessage());
            }

            throw new Exception($e->getMessage());                    

        }
```

Here is where the problem is & it doesn't enter the mysql_error() section..

```
protected function removeMainEntry($lid) {

    $lid = (int) $lid;

    // Remove from database
    $query = "DELET FROM lists WHERE id=" . $lid . " LIMIT 1";
    $sql = mysql_query($query, $this->db_connection);

    if (mysql_error()) {
        $etext = 'Problem removing list main entry from database.';
        $log_error = $etext . ' MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error() . '. Query: ' . $query;
        log_site_error($log_error);
        throw new Exception($etext);
    }

}
```

Here is the code from those functions I used..

```
if (!function_exists('beginTransaction')) {

    function beginTransaction($dblink) {

        $query = "BEGIN";
        mysql_query($query, $dblink);

        if (mysql_error()) {
            $etext = 'Problem adding new list data to database.';
            $log_error = $etext . ' MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error() . '. Query: ' . $query;
            log_site_error($log_error);
            throw new Exception($etext);            
        }

    }

}

if (!function_exists('commitChanges')) {

    function commitChanges($dblink) {

        $query = "COMMIT";
        mysql_query($query, $dblink);

        if (mysql_error()) {
            $etext = 'Problem adding new list data to database.';
            $log_error = $etext . ' MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error() . '. Query: ' . $query;
            log_site_error($log_error);
            throw new Exception($etext);            
        }

    }    

}

if (!function_exists('rollback')) {

    function rollback($dblink, $error = '') {

        $query = "ROLLBACK";
        mysql_query($query, $dblink);

        if (mysql_error()) {
            $etext = $error . ' Additionally there was a problem rolling back the changes in the database. Please check the logs.';
            $log_error = $etext . ' MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error() . '. Query: ' . $query;
            log_site_error($log_error);
            throw new Exception($etext);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Can you provide the actual error message? What happens when you try the query directly in a mysql console?

Comment: Can you try `mysql_error($dblink)`?

Comment: Don't tell me the problem is the `DELET` ...

Comment: @Pekka `mysql_error()` without arguments assumes the most recently executed mysql function so it should work without that.

Comment: What is your error level setting?  Can you set it temporarily to E_ALL?

Comment: @ring0:  He specifically states 'So I checked out the code & found out I had a problem with my query'.  He knows the query is wrong.  He's wondering why the code in the if statement isn't running.

Comment: @Pekka it also appears that with multiple connections you **must** provide the db link. i just checked the comments on the docs page

Comment: @Scott if no connection is specified, `mysql_error()` assumes the *most recently created mySQL connection*, and we don't know how many connections his application is dealing with.

Comment: @eykanal Well there is no error produced.... that's the problem lol..... when I try it in the console I get: Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELET FROM lists WHERE id=2 LIMIT 1' at line 1  -- which is correct.

Comment: Heh, looks like it is the fact that `DELETE` has an "e" at the end, like @ring0 said.

Comment: @pekka I have thought of trying that, though I didn't think that would have much use since it was the last used connection anyway. Only running the one connection btw. :)

@ring0 - Exactly.... that's what I'm saying. So WHY isn't that returning true on mysql_error() ?

@mellamokb I guess I can give that a shot... though that only deals with the reported errors on screen so not sure how that will help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you delete 0 rows, it will likely still be considered a success.  Use [mysql_affected_rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) to make sure you actually did anything.

Comment: I thought this didn't really work well when using transactions. At least that has been my experience. Although that was probably because I did it after the whole transaction, which makes sense lol -- though shouldn't this still throw an error since the query is malformed?

Comment: It will give you a -1 if you error, 0 if no rows change, or a number of rows.